# Obtener JSON de servicio web en JAVA

Tags: java, json, url, servicio

estoy iniciándome en la programación de bases de datos online y su comunicación con una aplicación local como puede ser una aplicación de escritorio JAVA o Android.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Teniendo configurado en una URL un servicio PHP que me devuelve todos los datos de la base de datos en un JSON, como puedo obtenerlos por ejemplo en JAVA? Como me conecto y hago la petición para guardarlos en una variable local?

PD: Podéis hacer click en el enlace para comprobar que estoy devolviendo un JSON válido.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto de esta forma, por si a alguien le vale. Funciona de perlas obteniendo como salida del system.out el valor del JSON mencionado anteriormente.

```
package consumidor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class a {

  private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("LA URL DE TU SERVICIO");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Si has dado con la solución, cuando te deje, márcala como aceptada, pulsando sobre la V al lado de tu respuesta. Así ayudará a los futuros usuarios que tengan la misma duda

Comment: Sí, ya tenía pensado, en 15 minutos ya me deja hacerlo.